# Selenium: Chrome suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a scraping script that worked perfectly, but then out of the blue suddenly stopped. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/myproject/scraping_all.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: unable to discover open pages)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Google Chrome version is: `Google Chrome 120.0.6099.109`

And this is how I set up the options for the scraping, as well:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/user/myproject')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

What's going on here? Is there something I should update besides Chrome, and how? Or is my setup wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check the chrome driver version? Seems you do not have the compatible chrome driver version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, KunduK. I thought that as of selenium 4.10.0 the driver manager is fully integrated (and will download drivers as needed). Besides this, when I do chromedriver -v, there's nothing there. Am I missing something?